# mysql group by query (very close)

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (simplified):

> - orders (orderid, date)
> - orderlines (lineid, orderid, userid)
> - users (userid, name)

I would like a list of numbers of orders per user grouped by year and month orders by username. The reason why order lines have the user id is that an order line can be changed by another user. The following gives me a list of numbers of order lines, but it needs to count the orders only:

```
SELECT 
  users.name, 
  COUNT(orders.orderid) AS number, 
  MONTH(orders.date) AS month, 
  YEAR(orders.date) AS year
FROM orders
INNER JOIN orderlines ON orders.orderid = orderlines.orderid
INNER JOIN users ON orderlines.userid = users.userid
GROUP BY orderlines.userid, YEAR(order.date), MONTH(order.date)
ORDER BY users.name, orders.date
```

I'm feeling I'm very close...

Current output is:

```
name | number | month | year 
---------------------------- 
jeff | 1000   | 1     | 2018  
jeff | 1100   | 2     | 2018
```

Should be:

```
name | number | month | year 
---------------------------- 
jeff | 100    | 1     | 2018  
jeff | 110    | 2     | 2018
```

The number currently shown is the number of order lines, but I would like it to be the number of orders.

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result

Comment: Do you realy have blanks in your table names `order lines`? I think you will get Errors if you run the query

Comment: @Jens like I said, it's simplified, those are not the real names. I will add sample data.

Comment: it is not simplyfied. bacause we do not know what is `order lines.order id` it only confuse the reader

Comment: @Jens order id is the unique id from the table orders, so it's a reference to know which order lines are connected to which order.

Comment: can you please add sample (input) data and take real column names

Comment: @Jens I have changed names and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below: you need to use users.name in group by, also it should be in your order by clause as your question says it, another thing is as you want to know the count of order per user, so it should be count distinct orderid

```
SELECT users.name, COUNT(distinct orders.orderid), MONTH(orders.date), YEAR(orders.date)
FROM orders
INNER JOIN orderlines ON orders.orderid = orderlines.orderid
INNER JOIN users ON order lines.userid = users.userid
GROUP BY users.name, YEAR(order.date), MONTH(order.date)
ORDER BY users.name
```

Comment: Someone had downvoted this answer... it was on -1 and I re-upvoted it, it is now to 0 after my upvote. The answer is good. the `distinct orders.orderid` part is the one that solves the `1000` instead of `100` issue of the OP. I never understand how/why people would downvote a correct answer, without bothering to explain their gesture. Too bad we can't see the downvote log.

Comment: @Gabriel, thank u. There are some watcher who asks question to op and if in the meanwhile someone answer it correctly, they don't like it and give donwvote. what i think is they have some psychological disorder.